# Select ids for distinct value with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns: unique id, recipients, sent_date and status.

I would like select ids for distinct recipients when sent_date > xx and status = 'something'

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EmailMessage 
WHERE Recipients in
    (SELECT Recipients 
     FROM EmailMessage
     GROUP BY Recipients 
     HAVING COUNT(Recipients)=1)
and sent_date > '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
and status = 'failed'
```

But this produces too few results and something seems not right. I am using SQL Server MS.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  In particular, what does "distinct recipient" mean?

Comment: This does not select distinct recipients. Your subquery selects all recipients that have received only one message. (If "recipients" is actually a comma-delimited list of recipients, it selects unique recipient lists.)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like select ids for distinct recipients when sent_date > xx
>   and status = 'something'

This translated in sql is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Recipients  
FROM EmailMessage 
WHERE 
  sent_date > '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
  AND 
  status = 'failed'
```

or

```
SELECT Recipients  
FROM EmailMessage 
WHERE 
  sent_date > '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
  AND 
  status = 'failed'
GROUP BY Recipients
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to get the IDs for distinct recipients, not the distinct recipients

Comment: Which column is the id of the recipient?

Comment: Is the unique ID column. I want to get those IDs only and I think this one will work: SELECT Max(Id) as Id, Recipients from EmailMessage
where [sent] > '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
and [status] = 'failed'
GROUP BY Recipients

Comment: If this column is **unique** then all the values are different from each other. You don't need distinct or group by, just a simple `select id...`

Comment: Yes but recipients are not unique, and I want to select only those IDS, where recipients are distinct + the where clause I have added above. Anyway the query works now for me, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This returns rows where the failure and date conditions are true:

```
SELECT em.*
FROM EmailMessage 
WHERE sent_date >= '2019-01-01' AND status = 'failed';
```

I'm not sure what "distinct recipient" means.  But you can get one row per recipient using window functions (or some other method):

```
SELECT em.*
FROM (SELECT em.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recipient ORDER BY sent_date) as seqnum
      FROM EmailMessage 
      WHERE sent_date >= '2019-01-01' AND status = 'failed'
     ) em
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```